# Type Error: cannot read property ' map ' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I am try to run an unit test for the following code
here is where the error is pointing to:

```
populateActionDropdown = (actionList) => {
    let actions = actionList.map(action => {
        if (action.Name != 'Sign Out') {
            let layout = ''
            if (action.Command.includes('Layout')) {
                if (/\(([^)]+)\)/.exec(action.Command)) {
                    layout = '/' + /\(([^)]+)\)/.exec(action.Command)[1].toLowerCase();
                }
            }
```

This is how I have been setting up most of my unit test. But I'm having problems calling props that contains map or sort next to it.
Example : this.props.something.map() or props.sort().
How could i mock actionList to make sure map gets called

Thanks

Unit test code below :

```
describe('ActionMenu ', () => {

    let tree;
    let baseProps;
    let mockaction = {
        actionId: "test",
        name: "test",
        map: "test",
    };
    let mocksetTarget;
    let mocksetAction;
    let mockmodule = {
        name: "test module name",
    };
    let mockactionMenuDropdownOpen;
    let mockactionMenuToggle;
    let mockactionList;

    beforeEach(() => {
        baseProps = {
            action: mockaction,
            setTarget: mocksetTarget,
            setAction: mocksetAction,
            module: mockmodule,
            actionMenuDropdownOpen: mockactionMenuDropdownOpen,
            actionMenuToggle: mockactionMenuToggle,
            actionList: mockactionList,
        }
    })

    it(' Should render with all of the props', () => {
        tree = renderer.create(<BrowserRouter><ActionMenuComponent {...baseProps}
        />
        </BrowserRouter>)
        let treeJson = tree.toJSON()
        expect(treeJson).toMatchSnapshot();
        tree.unmount()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I'm having problems calling props that contains `map` or `sort` next
>   to it. Example : `this.props.something.map()` or `props.sort()`.

To make your test pass, assign the following value to your `mockactionList`:

```
let mockactionList = [
  {
    actionId: "test",
    Name: "test",
    Command: []
  },
  {
    actionId: "test2",
    Name: "test2",
    Command: []
  }
];
```

Comment: what about actionList ? do i change anything on it ?

Comment: Thanks again, so if theres sort or map - just add a COMMAND : []

Comment: You're welcome. If it involves `.sort()` or `.map()`, you have to to make sure that the props you passed is an array else it's gonna throw an `undefined` error. One way you could also handle that is to use fallback value so instead of `let actions = actionList.map`, you can do it like `let actions = ( actionList || [] ).map` when you're using those functions.

Comment: i think I might to apply the same concept to replace() as well. Do I include anything inside of   baseProps = {
    ...baseProps,
    actionList: {},       when I try to pass the test without actionList props
     };

Comment: If `actionList` is not a required prop, you could change your implementation inside your `populateActionDropdown` to this `let actions = (actionList || []).map` so it won't cause the error if it's not included in the props. Same goes with your other props that use the `.sort` or other functions that would throw undefined.

Comment: I added a picture of module props. i might have to apply the same method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186936/discussion-between-ana-liza-pandac-and-user91).